# Calculate checksum fails when strings are differently encoded

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, checksum

I have a routine for checksum calculation and it fails for string which have accented characters, to handle accented characters I convert the string to a byte array using the encoding which the string is actually from, for ex: a string will contains accented characters appearing as François^Frédérique^ and the encoding it uses is 'CP437', and if after doing such the checksum calculation fails, thus can you let me know if there is something more I need to be doing.

```
        byte[] frameArray = frame.getBytes(m_fileEncoding);
        int frameLength = frameArray.length;
        int idx =0;
        while (idx < frameLength )
        {
            int c = frameArray[idx];

            sum1 += c;

            if (sum1 >= 256)
            {
                sum1 -= 256;
            }
            idx++;
        }

        sum1 = 256 - sum1;

        calculatedChecksum = Integer.toHexString(sum1 & 0xff).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - the same checksum for two files which represent the same content in different encodings, or the checksum for the original bytes in the file?

Comment: Hello Jon, it is the checksum for original bytes in the file, and the checksum I am calculating is being validated by sending it to a device which then rejects it(only for cases where the string contains accented characters)

Comment: I suggest you just check the raw bytes of the file then - don't load it as a string at all to start with. There are ways in which that can be a lossy conversion - best to skip the text decoding/encoding part entirely.

Comment: You are very correct when I validated it against the byte, I calculate the right checksum, the problem being when I append the checksum to the string and send the string using the required encoding, it fails to validate, could possibly because of the lossy conversion when I save the encoded stream to string.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're sending where, to be honest. You should probably give more context in the question.